# Write permission for file system in Pantheon hosting

Tags: files

I am using three different kind of environments like *Dev*, *Test*, and *Live* under Pantheon hosting.

The file systems for *Dev* and *Test* are working fine and those have write permissions too. When I try to give the write permission for the *Live* environment, it shows a *permission denied* error.

It shows the temp directory doesn't exist, but the temp directory is there in my server. I don't know how it happens. Can anyone give the solution for that?